# How can I connect gcp in Apache Airflow using Python without using local os.environ

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, credentials, identity-management

I'm currently using Apache Airflow for orchestrating my DAGs and testing my programs locally. In my code, I have a function that requires a connection to Google Cloud to provide identity tokens for my tasks. The function looks something like this:

```
def get_identity_token(service_url):
    creds, project = google.auth.default()
    auth_req = Request()
    token = id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, service_url)
    return token
```

Currently, I set the GCP credentials in my code like this:

`os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path/to/credentials.json"`

I'm trying to figure out how to establish this connection to Airflow without relying on local os.environ for setting the GCP credentials. I have also tried using the Airflow UI to copy the JSON key but I'm unsure how to use this copied key in my code.

I'd like to know if there are any best practices or preferred ways to connect to Airflow and use the credentials securely. Any advice or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a Connection rather than an env var.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html

When you configure a connection via the UI, you can configure a connection of type gcp. Then you can use that connection via a hook.